# Why does MailApp.sendEmail from Google Spreadsheet Script not Work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps

I'm *Trying* to send email using `MailApp.sendEmail` in a Google Spreadsheet Script following *this* example: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/ by [@mhawksey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1027723/mhawksey)

> see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mhY_hJMMPTmxq3TFAUHK0tKFhGYBpzus-dXE3U5TQdc/edit?usp=sharing

The **Test web app for your latest code.** function ***works***. (*email is sent*)

[image: 12 8-test-your-code]

But when I try to trigger the `sendEmail()` via a `POST` request it does not work.

I'm following the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

And yet when I trigger the `sendEmail()` function from my script, it does not send an email.

What am I doing wrong?

Looked at:

- [MailApp.sendEmail Not Working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355823/mailapp-sendemail-not-working)
- [Google script mailapp.sendEmail only works with my email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697291/google-script-mailapp-sendemail-only-works-with-my-email-address)

But I want to *understand* if I am doing something wrong...

Full Steps and code: https://github.com/nelsonic/web-form-to-google-sheet#12-google-apps-script

Comment: do you get an error? Can you reproduce the issue with a simple script?

Comment: most likely you forgot to save a new version and publish using that version. see versioning in official help.

Comment: @ZigMandel thanks!! For others: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thanks to [@ZigMandel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2213940/zig-mandel) for pointing me the *right direction* ... here are the steps for anyone else facing this issue:

#### Invoke the `MailApp.sendEmail` Method

In your Google Spreadsheet *Script* call:

```
MailApp.sendEmail("recipient.address@gmail.com", // to
                  "sender.name@gmail.com",       // from
                  "Your Subject Goes Here",      // email subject
                  "What ever you want to say");  // email body
```

As per the docs: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailto-replyto-subject-body

For this new functionality to *work* in your script you
will need to "***Save a New Version***" and ***(Re-)Deploy your App***! (*simply clicking the "Save" is* ***Not Enough***!)

#### Save a *New Version* of your Script

It's not immediately *obvious* but you have to *click* on "*Manage Versions...*" see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions

[image: 19 google-script-no-save-new-version]

Then *create* your new version:

[image: 20 google-script-save-new-version]

#### Re-Publish the *Updated* Script as a Web App

[image: 20 a-publish]

Select the *latest* project version to deploy:

[image: 21 deploy-new-version]

Click "OK". No need to update the script *url* in your HTML form
(*it does not change* - *there are pros & cons to this...*)

[image: 22 1-deploy-as-web-app]

### Done.

For the ***complete solution*** see: https://github.com/nelsonic/web-form-to-google-sheet